# Why I don't see any loader when I refresh pages like facebook?

Tags: session, authentication, web, token, protected

I want to ask you how does sites like Facebook etc. handle user authentication on the page refresh? I wonder why I don't see any loader when I refresh the page and I'm on the protected route (e.g. my profile settings).

When I create an application I use following authentication flow:

1. Load the application
2. Show authentication process loader to the user.
3. Get user session token from the cookie.
4. Send authentication request with the token to the backend.
5. Validate the token on the backend.
6. Send a response to the client with the status code 200 if token is valid or status code 401 if token is invalid.
7. Receive a response on the client side and hide the loader.
8. Show protected route to user if he is authenticated or redirect to the login page when he is not authenticated.

So with such a flow initial loader is a necessity, how facebook is able to omit that?

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to Stack Overflow.

I'm not sure your question is valid - pretty much every page on Facebook requires you to be authenticated (not just the profile page), and authenticated access is a common feature of pretty much every major website; they rarely show loading bars.

We don't know exactly how Facebook is built, but it's a fair guess they use React; you can read up on how to manage authentication on React [here](https://medium.appbase.io/how-to-implement-authentication-for-your-react-app-cf09eef3bb0b).

Your flow is predicated on the assumption that there is an "application" to load, and that the authentication request will take substantial amounts of time. If your token validation is fast, this assumption is probably incorrect. You do see "loading" animations on React apps - if you scroll down your timeline on FB really fast, you see the circle; this is probably partly network, partly retrieving the posts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By saying application - I mean the client side application (html, js, css). Nevertheless, I don't understand why my assumptions are incorrect. We can not be sure about what amount of time auth validation process may take - it depends on many conditions (network connection quality or server workload for example). Sometimes it may took few seconds. Of course, I know that in the other parts of facebook application like timeline we can find loaders, but that's obvious.

Comment: Also, in that article about managing authentication, they use the same flow as mine - with the initial loader shown during token validation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's possible because authentication can be done on the server side using cookies. They validate user token when user enter the page and after this they render desired version of page (different for authenticated and different for not authenticated user).